# Import glyphs from another font with fontforge

Tags: linux, fonts, font-awesome, glyph, fontforge

Hi I'm using Inconsolata for powerline font in linux (link [1](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata)). Now I want to had some extra symbols. I've successfully added the awesome font symbols from the Inconsolata patched fonts in link [2](https://github.com/gabrielelana/awesome-terminal-fonts/tree/patching-strategy/patched) to my own copy of Inconsolata for powerline font (i.e. I can successfully copy glyphs to my font and they appear on the terminal).

However when I try to add icons from other fonts, namely the battery icons from Typicons (see link [3](https://github.com/TimPietrusky/weloveiconfonts/tree/master/app/api/fonts/typicons)) they simply do not appear in the terminal. I've scaled and changed multiple properties but it's always the same.

I'm doing fc-cache -fv and I've checked that if I manually create a glyph it appears after an fc-cache. I'm completely lost here, I'm sure it must be something simple but I've already lost a lot of hours with this and the glyphs never appear in the terminal no matter what I do :-(

Comment: How do they "not appear in the terminal"? What method did you use to try and show them?

Comment: I'm using urxvt as the terminal. I press shift+ctrl to input a Unicode symbol. Only a rectangle appear. However I have already discovered the problem. I'm going to update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding few glyphs from each to a new font file project. If it is a symbol-only font and you don't care/need to follow Unicode assignments, use codepoints for alphabetical characters and numbers.
Generate your file and check for errors. Fix any issues reported by FontForge.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the problem. In two words `lbearing` and `rbearing`. They must be the same as the other glyphs. The size is also important. Even with a similar `lbearing` and `rbearing` if the size of the glyph is too big it will not appear.